# How can I create a recursive algorithm to find permutations given two letters?

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive program to generate permutations with repetitions of letters X and O, so for example, if I wanted permutations of XO, it would give:
XO, OX, XX, OO
Or if I wanted permutations of XOX, it would give:
XXX, OOO, XOO, XXO, OXX, OOX, XOX, OXO

So far, I have this:

```
    public class driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        permutation("XO");
    }
    
        public static void permutation(String input){ 
            permutation("", input); 
        }
        
        private static void permutation(String perm, String word) {
            if (word.isEmpty()) {
                System.err.println(perm + word);

            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                    permutation(perm + word.charAt(i), word.substring(0, i) 
                                            + word.substring(i + 1, word.length()));
                }
            }
    }

}
```

However, the output for XO would give XO and OX only. How would I go about modifying something like the examples I gave above?

This is the end goal, once I figure how to generate the permutations correctly, as I am first going to find permutations, add each individual perm to their own array (going to use 2d array), and use the array to generate final words. I will replace the hidden elements each with the each array of permutations found, so to create full words:
[image: This is the end goal, as I am first going to find permutations, add them to an array, and use the array to generate final words.]

Comment: How is `OXO` a *permutation* (which is a fancy word for "rearrangement") of `XOX`?

Comment: I guess it isnt? I guess im trying to find all unique combinations for a given string?

Comment: `OXO` isn't a *unique combination" of `XOX`, either.

Comment: @ScottHunter He's looking for permutations with repetition, in this case of letters X and O with given length.

Comment: In your question , for word ```XOX`` , you have given output as ```XXX, OOO, XOO, XXO, OXX, OOX, XOX, OXO``` , but where does ```OOO``` comes ??? are you saying you want the combination of each letter in a string for given length?

Comment: @Umeshwaran Yes, exactly. For simplicity sake, lets just say I want n length of all possible words with letters X and O, and the words do not have to have either X or O at the same time.

Comment: This approach is way too expensive. Start by creating a recursion tree. You need exactly 2 tail-recursive calls. For example: `void p(int start, int max, String s) {if(start == max) {System.out.println(s); return;} p(start + 1, max, s + 'X'); p(start + 1, max, s + 'O');}`. You can invoke it likewise: `p(0, 3, "");`

Comment: @UsamaSaleem These are not permutations or combinations. These are variations with repetition.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the recursive permutation using the following code .

```
public class driver { 
  
    // Function to print all the permutations of str 
    static void printPermutn(String str, String ans) 
    { 
  
        // If string is empty 
        if (str.length() == 0) { 
            System.out.print(ans + " "); 
            return; 
        } 
  
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { 
  
            // ith character of str 
            char ch = str.charAt(i); 
  
            // Rest of the string after excluding  
            // the ith character 
            String ros = str.substring(0, i) +  
                         str.substring(i + 1); 
  
            // Recurvise call 
            printPermutn(ros, ans + ch); 
        } 
    } 
  
    // Driver code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String s = "XOX"; 
        printPermutn(s, ""); 
    } 
}
```

It would output the following : `XOX XXO OXX OXX XXO XOX`

Link : https://ideone.com/ClZYk4

Comment: However, is it possible to create combinations such that there is not a requirement to have both letters in a combination at the same time? For simplicity sake, lets just say I want n length of all possible words with letters X and O, and the words do not have to have either X or O at the same. So in this case, OOO and XXX would also be valid outputs. 

In this instance, the total possible combinations would be 2^(length of string input) --> so XO would be 4 combinations, XOX would be 8 combinations, etc.

Comment: Check my another solution . That addresses your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for your requirement.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Sample2 {
    // static set that stores all combinations
    public static Set<String> combinations = new TreeSet<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create an alphabet to work with
        String s = "XOX";
        char[] alphabet = s.toCharArray();
        // Find all possible combinations of this alphabet in the string size of 3
        possibleStrings(s.length(), alphabet, "");
        combinations.forEach(l -> {
            System.out.println(l);
        });
    }

    public static void possibleStrings(int maxLength, char[] alphabet, String curr) {

        // If the current string has reached it's maximum length
        if (curr.length() == maxLength) {
//              System.out.println(curr);
            combinations.add(curr);

            // Else add each letter from the alphabet to new strings and process these new
            // strings again
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
                String oldCurr = curr;
                curr += alphabet[i];
                possibleStrings(maxLength, alphabet, curr);
                curr = oldCurr;
            }
        }
    }
//  }
}
```

The output would be

```
OOO
OOX
OXO
OXX
XOO
XOX
XXO
XXX
```

This works for any given string .

Comment: @Usama . Did you try this solution . Did it work for u?

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
static public void printPermutation(String word) {

    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

    char[] state = new char[chars.length];

    Arrays.fill(state, ' ');
    helper(chars, state, 0);

}

static public void helper(
    char[] chars,
    char[] state,
    int index
) {

    if (index == chars.length) {
        System.out.println(new String(state));
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {

        if (state[i] == ' ') {
            state[i] = chars[index];
            helper(chars, state, index + 1);
            state[i] = ' ';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Need output like:OOO
OOX
OXO
OXX
XOO
XOX
XXO
XXX

For "XOX" for example. Reptitions, i.e OOO are allowed. Yours only gives 6 outputs instead of 8